# How to fit data with Log normal CDF

Tags: python, data-fitting, cdf

i'm a new user of Python and I'm trying to fit some experimental data with CDF's. The data are as following, and they should be plot in x-axis log scale:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array([0.995, 3.003, 5.908, 10.525, 13.617, 24.321, 33.917, 47.843, 64.172, 91.353, 126.745, 174.118, 225.059, 292.998, 369.133, 640.295, 828.169, 1255.39, 1496.613, 1942.785])

y=np.array([0.142, 0.2, 0.25, 0.36, 0.498, 0.616, 0.599, 0.7, 0.835, 1.102, 1.083, 1.225, 1.133, 1.165, 1.298, 1.365, 1.298, 1.373, 1.409, 1.538])

pyplot.xscale('log')

plt.plot(x,y,'r.')
```

I found a testimony from a fellow user that had fitted a data using the following approach:

```py
from scipy.special import erf
from lmfit import Model

def gaussian_cdf(x,amp,mu,sigma):
    return (amp/2.0)*(1+erf((mu-x)/(sigma*np.sqrt(2.0))))


model = Model(gaussian_cdf,prefix='g1_') + Model(gaussian_cdf,prefix='g2_')

params = model.make_params(g1_amp=0.50,g1_mu=94,g1_sigma=1.,
                          g2_amp=0.50,g2_mu=98,g2_sigma=1.)

params['g1_sigma'].min=0
params['g2_sigma'].min=0

result = model.fit(y,params,x = x)

print(result.fit_report())

comps=result.eval_components(result.params,x=x)


plt.plot(x,y,'r.',label='data')
plt.plot(x,result.best_fit,'k-',label='fit')
plt.plot(x,comps['g1_'],'b--',label='g1_')
plt.plot(x,comps['g2_'],'g--',label='g2_')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjhkg.png)

But when I try to adapt this code to my own problem (whose data are shown above), which deals with LogNormal distributions pdf's & cdf's, the result isn't good.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7lJ9.png)

If someone could help me with it, I'd appreciate so much!

Thanks in advance

Comment: the code you post looks like a good example to follow, but you don't post the actual code you used.  That makes it very difficult to know what went wrong. Post the code you actually ran.

Comment: Hi, M Newville. Thank you for your feedback. I used exactly this same code, but instead of x, I used np.log(x) in order to compute a lognormal distribution. But the result was that shown in the second plot

Comment: `log(x)`?  Or did you mean to fit `log(y)` to the log of the the cdf?  FWIW, this is why posting the code you actually used is helpful, especially in comparison to code that works but is not what you used.   The answer for why your code doesn't work is probably found in that difference. But we don't know what that difference is.

Comment: On a related note, `np.log` is the natural log and `np.log10` is the log base 10.

Comment: Do you really mean you want to fit a [log-normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) distribution function to your data? Because that's not what your data seems like to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can fit a line of the form y = a * log10(b * x + h) + k (which seems to fit your data better than a log-normal distribution) by using [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and defining your log function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=np.array([0.995, 3.003, 5.908, 10.525, 13.617, 24.321, 33.917, 47.843, 64.172, 91.353, 126.745, 174.118, 225.059, 292.998, 369.133, 640.295, 828.169, 1255.39, 1496.613, 1942.785])

y=np.array([0.142, 0.2, 0.25, 0.36, 0.498, 0.616, 0.599, 0.7, 0.835, 1.102, 1.083, 1.225, 1.133, 1.165, 1.298, 1.365, 1.298, 1.373, 1.409, 1.538])

def log(x, a, b, h, k):
    return a*np.log10(b*x + h) + k

# Provide guesses to the parameters
params = [6, 1, 0, 0]#, .2]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(log, x, y, p0=params)

plt.plot(x,y,'r.')
plt.plot(x, log(x, *popt), 'k--', label = 'fit: a = %.2f b = %.2f h = %.2f k = %.2f ' 
% tuple(popt)) #locl = %.2f scale = %.2f
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
#plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Without the log scale, you get the fit that looks like

[image]

With the log scale, your fit looks like

[image]